# Syntax Highlighting

Tags: java, swing, syntax-highlighting, jtextcomponent

I created a Summer project for myself and decided that I wanted to write a simple text/code editor. I think everything has been going well so far. I created a basic GUI and can do simple operations like Open, Save, and Create files.

Right now I am doing syntax highlighting by reading the words as I open a file but this has turned out to be really messy and it doesn't highlight the syntax if someone is just typing in the GUI.

So I'd like some ideas of how to go about syntax highlighting so that it works for both opening files and typing in the window.

Also, if anyone has any time I'd love to hear comments about my code, this is the repository: https://mcmillhj.beanstalkapp.com/jtexteditor/browse

The main files are JTextEditor.java and ui/JTextEditorUI.java

Comment: Have you looked at the [Highlighter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Highlighter.html) and [HighlightPainter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Highlighter.HighlightPainter.html) classes? There's an example in the [How to Use Text Fields](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) tutorial.

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't have used the term highlighter, it seems ambiguous now that I think about it. Those classes literally highlight the text that you want. I just want to make the keywords different colors from the regular words. sorry for the confusion. Thank you for your link.

Comment: I appreciate the clarification! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should start reading about [lexical analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) , you can also use [JLex](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/modern/java/JLex/) for getting tokens from the content of the file ... you should also read a bit about compilers (which is not going to be easy)

Comment: I have used something similar called JFlex to create a tokenizer for an interpreter I wrote. So you're saying I should tokenize the entire contents of my file then step through the tokens searching for keywords and such? Thank you for your link by the way.

Comment: yes ... or if you don't like to tokenize and search through the tokens in two different steps, you can tell the GUI about the place of the tokens while parsing, to highlight it (using an observer pattern or something, by notifying the observer when a token is found) which would probably take less time than doing it in different steps.